# Typescript 1.6 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I have a problem to run a Typescript 1.6 in Visual Studio 2013. I have installed Typescript(Web Essentials) for Visual Studio and change TypeScriptToolsVersion to 1.6. But Typescript compiler cant understand(for example) union types.

In Visual Studio 2015 Typscript 1.6 works with no problems.

Thank you.

Comment: have you installed the 1.6.2 for VS 2013? Not just 1.6.3 vor VS 2015? also, be sure you've uninstalled all older...

Comment: Ohh, that was the issue. Thank you, If you repost your comment as an answer I would accept it with pleasure:)

Comment: If that helped, great ;) really. Enjoy amazing Typescript, sir ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, we would need

- 1.6.2 for VS 2013
- 1.6.3 for VS 2015

Both could be found here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/#Download

I'd also suggest to uninstall or previous versions...